# Jenkins pipeline works in UI but not from SCM

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I decided to port all my Jenkins job over to Jenkins-pipeline. I did a simple test with the following Jenkinsfiles in to the UI:

```
pipeline {
agent any 
stages {
    stage('Clone Repo') {
        steps {
            git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxx ', url: 'https://github.com/xxxxx/xxx.git'
        }
    }

}
```

}

This works fine. I created a repo in github and checked in this Jenkinsfile. I changes Jenkins to Pipeline script from SCM and it is finding the Jenkinsfile but falling over with the error message below. I know I've missed something basic, but reading all the documentations; I couldn't work it out. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Here's the Jenkins job. There's a jenkinsfile the ndh_poc.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you configured your job to use pipeline script from SCM ?

Comment: I've included above.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Script Path field, **specify the location (and name) of your Jenkinsfile**. This location is the one that Jenkins checks out/clones the repository containing your Jenkinsfile, which should match that of the repository’s file structure.

In your case if your jenkinsfile name is `Jenkinsfile` and is present within the directory `ndh_poc` at the root of your repository then the Script Path should be `ndh_poc/Jenkinsfile`